# Массив коллекций в Котлине

Tags: kotlin, синтаксис, syntax

Как правильно объявить и инициализировать массив коллекций на Котлине,

например Array of ArrayLists of Ints ??
В Джаве писал так:

```
ArrayList<T>[] name = new ArrayList[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот код на Java:

```
ArrayList<T>[] name = new ArrayList[SIZE];
```

в Kotlin будет выглядеть так:

```
val yourArrayInKotlin = Array(SIZE) { arrayListOf<Int>() }
```

Но вообще вместо `arrayListOf<Int>()` лучше использовать `intArrayOf()`